# geting maximu value in a table column

Tags: yii2

I am trying to get maximum value of id column

```
$taskid = (new Query())->select('MAX(id)')->from('member');

echo $taskid;
```

unfortunate I got the below text

```
O:12:"yii\db\Query":20:{s:6:"select";a:1:{i:0;s:7:"MAX(id)";}s:12:"selectOption";N;s:8:"distinct";N;s:4:"from";a:1:{i:0;s:21:"member";}s:7:"groupBy";N;s:4:"join";N;s:6:"having";N;s:5:"union";N;s:6:"params";a:0:{}s:18:"queryCacheDuration";N;s:20:"queryCacheDependency";N;s:27:"yii\base\Component_events";a:0:{}s:35:"yii\base\Component_eventWildcards";a:0:{}s:30:"yii\base\Component_behaviors";N;s:5:"where";N;s:5:"limit";N;s:6:"offset";N;s:7:"orderBy";N;s:7:"indexBy";N;s:16:"emulateExecution";b:0;}
```

please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Maximum id value of Member model:

```
use app\models\Member;
// ...
echo Member::find()->max('id');
```